# The Like button is not populating

Tags: facebook-like

The like button on my site, is not correctly populating the description on the homepage. Why?

```
<title> Get Your FREE Samples & Health Offers!  </title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<meta name="google-site-verification" content="jrQQnK64_8oK14HSeSP071dzignAPnHEreVOhhU_7LY" />

<meta name="Description" content="Get Your FREE Samples &amp; Health Offers! " />
<meta name="Keywords" content="Get Your FREE Samples &amp; Health Offers! " />
<meta property="og:title" content="Skin Care Sample Test111"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="www.qualityhealth.com/mediaLanding?path=65629"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="www.qualityhealth.com/resources/images/advil_campaign.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="QualityHealth"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="This is where the body copy will go for this skin care sample test."/>
```

Answer (score 1):

For a start, your `og:url` and `og:image` tags are invalid because they're missing the protocol identifier (i.e should be `http://www.qualityhealth.com`)

Run your pages through [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and see what else you need to fix